# Find word position (not character position) in a string

Tags: string, list, sorting, position, date-sorting

I am sorting the words in a given paragraph from a text file. I have the line numbers and the number of occurrence of each word sorted out. However, I am having a bit of a trouble trying to get the word position number per line. I am using object list to sort the strings.

For example:

**Given line**

> I have a question about the word position number

**Output should be**

> question - line 1 position 4
>   about - line 1 position 5
>   position - line 1 position 8

Any useful suggestions how I should go about this? Below is my code.

```
public void visit() {
    ListNode p = lines.getFirstNode();
    if (word.length() < 4) {
        so.output(word + "\t\t\t\t" + count + "\t\t\t\t");
        while (p != null) {
            so.output(p.getInfo() + " ");
            p = p.getNext();
        }
        so.output("\n");

        ...
```

Comment: using object list to sort which strings? sort the lines? sort the words in the lines?

Comment: I am using object list to sort the given strings from file for the number of lines. Can I use that to sort the word position in the line or use a different method for word position?

Comment: yes, you can use a `split()` method to split each line into an array of words and then find the index that way. I can post a detailed answer if you like. It looks like you're using Java?

Comment: That will be fantastic! Yes I am using Java Eclipse. Thank you so much!

Comment: @eriese Do you happen to have any suggestions? I tried all day with different methods. Nothing came true. Quite frustrated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you're looking for

```
String line = "I have a question about the word position number";
String[] lineArray = line.split(" ");
int wordPos = Arrays.asList(lineArray).indexOf("question");
```

just remember that `wordPos` here is going to output to `3`, because arrays start counting from 0, so you'll probably want to add 1 to it when you're formatting your output string because users won't understand that.

Comment: of course, this will only give you the first position of a given word in a line, so let me know if you can't figure that one out for yourself.